# Replace 'normal' line-break with nothing (UTF-8?)

Tags: javascript, php

I`m working on a program that reads an xml-file, gets the right text with PHP and then displays with Javascript. Everything works fine but there is one problem: some xml elements have a line-break in their 'textfield'. That gives an Javascript error.
Example:

```
    <item>
           <itemschild>The problem is a line-break.


           </itemschild>
    </item>
```

This results in:

```
    $("#output").prepend("The problem is a line-break.


    ");
```

This gives the error. Is there a PHP regex to get rid of those line-breaks. Or maybe another solution. I hope you can help me!

Comment: `$output = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "", $output);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular php [`trim`](http://www.php.net/trim) should do it:

```
$("#output").prepend("<?php echo trim($yourvar) ?>");
```

To be safe against other possible problems (e.g., with quotes), you can use `json_encode`:

```
$("#output").prepend(<?php echo json_encode(trim($yourvar)) ?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use `$.trim`? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

```
$('#output').prepend($.trim("The problem is a line-break.


"));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/4ZW2L/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not a problem :) please mark this as the correct answer if it helped you.